# How can I do JQuery UI autocomplete under ul tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

This is my plugin with autocomplete(you can type C,B,..)

http://kolesnikg.github.io/

I want to do autocomplete just below ul tag(input field). How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JQuery UI there is class ".ui-autocomplete-loading" that control autocomplete content.

so i just add to my css file:

`.ui-autocomplete-loading {
    position: absolute;
    left: Xpx;
    top:Xpx;}`

and add style to tag UL in html file relative to which i want to place autocomplete:

`<ul id="myTags" class="ui-menu tagit-autocomplete" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;"></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener for the keypress on your input field, and each key concatenate it to a String, with that string filter the list of elements that are going to be displayed. After you filter them for each element left you insert in the inner html of the select an option or list item showing the element.

Comment: yea, but i use jquery ui  autocomlete, and it content is next to input field that placed in big ul field. I want to put autocomplete next to big ul field.

Comment: Could you provide a better description and some of your source code? If you could upload it to jsbin or plunker that would be great

Comment: thanks, i found in jqUI file the class ".ui-autocomplete-loading" that control autocomplete content and now all works good.